# SailsJS unable to set session cookie using NginX as reverse proxy

Tags: angular, nginx, socket.io, sails.js, reverse-proxy

I am using Nginx as a reverse proxy for my Sails.js backend application, but it seems that the session cookie is not being stored in the browser after a successful authentication.

My frontend is an angular2 app that connects using socket.io.

My Nginx config is:

```
    location ~ /api/(?<section>.+) {

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1338/$section;
        proxy_pass_header  Set-Cookie;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

    }
```

I connect using socket.io using this config:

```
    let opts = {
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8090",
        transports: ['polling', 'websocket'],
        path: 'api/socket.io'       
    }
    this.connect("http://127.0.0.1:8090", opts);
```

I if dont use a nginx reverse proxy the cookie is being set. What am I missing?

Comment: You should check the cookie's attributes - perhaps the domain or path is too specific and preventing its use through the proxy.

Comment: Hi. I was thinking about that as well, and I have gone through all the frontend and backend (sailsjs) code to make sure the hostname is set to 127.0.0.1 as I thought it might be a domain problem. There should be 2 cookies set; #1 is the 'io' cookie from socket.io (I guess) and it is being set. #2 is I should also get the 'sails.sid' cookie, but that one is missing. If I go directly to my sails app (bypassing the nginx proxy) I get the 'sails.sid' cookie.

Comment: @ChrisWorks did you ever find a solution to this?